# Date.Format for javascript date

Tags: javascript, go

I have an array of

```
struct {
    Date         time.Time
    PostedSample int
}
```

loaded from the appengine datastore which I want to output in a html/template for the [Google Visualization Time Line](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline#Data_Format). First I tried formatting the Date directly in the template with `{{.Date.Format "new Date(2006,1,2,15,4,5)"}}` but html/template escapes this so it appears as a quoted string in the html source. I then tried formatting the date into a `[]struct{Date template.JS; Value template.JS}` with the expression `template.JS(m.Date.Format("new Date(2006,1,2,15,4,5)"))` which almost works except the month is off by one, javascript wants January as 0. I could have the template generate a json of date parameters and write javascript turn that into Date objects or have go code which adjusts the template output. Please share a more elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: You might find this useful if you're parsing a lot of dates in JavaScript http://momentjs.com/

Comment: You may be able to add the date formatting to a function in the template funcmap. Have a look at http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs . Example at http://play.golang.org/p/pu66DfQIbJ .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a format function to the templates.

You can use your struct like so:

`{{.Date.Format "Mon 2 Jan 2006"}}`

The solution might be something like this:

`var date = new Date(parseInt({{.Date.Nanosecond }} /1000));`